# replace lines from file that match patterns in another file

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I am writing a script, but drawing blank at the moment in my head.

So basically, I have `1.txt`, which has a bunch of IPs like:

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

And I also have another file `2.txt`, which has something like this:

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3 bad ip
4.4.4.4
5.5.5.5
```

Anything in `1.txt` should be eliminated in `2.txt`, so after being processed, the `2.txt` should look like

```
4.4.4.4
5.5.5.5
```

Drawing a blank by trying to use the script

```
while line in `cat 2.txt` 
sed -i 's/"$line"//g' 2.txt
```

Anyone can give me some pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```
sed -r 's#(.*)#/\1/d#' file1 | sed -f - file2
```

Comment: This is great, but is there any way to eliminate the line instead of replacing it with a blank line?

Answer (score 3):

Here you can use `grep` alone.

```
grep -wv -f 1.txt 2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through 1.txt and store all values. Then iterate through the lines of 2.txt and if any of the values match any of the values from 1.txt don't store those. Only store values from 2.txt that don't match any from 1.txt.

Answer (score 1):

This awk 1-liner should do the job:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1];next} !($1 in a)' {1,2}.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next}{for(x in a) if(index($0,x)>0) next}1' file{1,2}
```